# How can I reject 443 port requests with IP in HTTP_HOST (Invalid HTTP_HOST header)?

Tags: django, nginx

How can I reject 443 port requests with IP in HTTP_HOST instead of domain (Invalid HTTP_HOST header)?

I already blocked IP:80 requests with

```
server {
        return 444;
}
```

in my config. But adding `listen 443` blocks all 443 requests – not just by IP.

Comment: Do look at this [answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/nginx-how-to-prevent-processing-requests-with-undefined-server-names-with-http)

Comment: Thanks, it really looks like http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/nginx-how-to-prevent-processing-requests-with-undefined-server-names-with-http duplicate. Too bad there is only a workaround present.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you want to whitelist or blacklist

Blacklisting:

```
server {
  # blacklisting
  listen 443;
  deny 11.22.33.44;
  deny 192.168.1.0/24; # also deny ranges
  allow all;
  location / {
    # normal config
  }
}
```

Whitelisting:

```
server {
  # whitelisting
  allow 11.22.33.44;
  allow 192.168.1.0/24; #ranges again
  deny all;
  location {
    # normal config
  }
}
```

also you can move the deny/allow inside location blocks, you can read more about allow and deny in the [http access module doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)

Comment: Thanks, but AFAIU, you slightly misunderstood the question due to the fact that I didn't describe my problem clearly enough. I've edited the question.